Add SWRL rules to ontology by using OWLAPI
I want to add SWRL rules to the ontology, however I may not know the contents of the body and head of the rules.
How can this be implemented using the OWLAPI? I don't use SWRLAPI because SWRLAPI throws an exception org.swrlapi.exceptions.SWRLRuleEngineException.

Can you provide more context? What do you mean "I may not know the contents of body and head"? At the point of creating the rule, these must be known, either as class or property expressions or as variables.

@Ignazio. I mean, the rules are set using classes and properties defined in the ontology, but how these predicates are combined is unknown.
Example:
I have A, B, C classes, dataProperty0, dataProperty1, dataProperty2 data properties and objProperty0, objProperty1. And rules obtained from an external file can have any combination of these classes and properties.

if the rules come from an external file, then you need to parse those rules first. Depending on the used syntax you might re(use) some parser of the OWL API, otherwise you'll need to w rite your own parser to create the OWL API SWRL objects. So, in which format is that external file containing the rules?

@UninformedUser. I use json to store rules, I also wrote a method that parses this json file into a Rules object, which has 3 ArrayLists, each of which contains rules divided into one of 3 blocks (for example, the first block defines the value dataProperty0, the second defines objProperty1, and the last block defines dataProperty2). I have an idea of implementing a parser from a string in a SWRL rule, but I'm not sure how best to implement the creation of atoms defining built-ins. Because these built-ins can be from 0 to several dozens.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
